# Rails 3.1 Deleted folder can I recover with git?

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-3.1

OK.  I was deleting precompiled assets in my public/assets folder.  I accidentally deleted an entire folder I had in there as well.  I checked out a repository and started webrick and the files seem to be loading, although when I look in the directory they aren't there?  how do i restore/move those files back into the public/assets directory?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you haven't commited the deletion. Check the changes that are pending with `git status` and use `git checkout` to restore a file to its last commited state ( HEAD ):

`git checkout -- file_path`

Git works on files not on directories.

Comment: Actually, I just did :  " git checkout -- ./ " after a careless rm, and it restored everything